# Gmail body template

Tags: gmail

I'm using MimeMessage setContent to send http body emails from my application.

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sessionProps());
            message.setSender(addressFrom);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(template, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

This template contains a button that calls my rest api (see code bellow).

```
<body>  
 .....
  <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="userAction()">Click Me!</button>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function userAction() {
        const response = fetch(restApi);
      const myJson = response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
       alert(myJson);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
```

My simple rest

```
@GetMapping("/hello/")
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I click the button inside gmail body email nothing is showing, Any thoughts ? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include [example] and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: Thank you, hopefully now is well described !!

Answer (score 0):

I found that email clients strip out javascript.

> I'm afraid such functionality, while theoretically possible, wouldn't
> be very practical given that most email clients strip out or disable
> JavaScript in order to prevent malicious code execution or other
> security issues.

[jQuery event not triggred in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868627/clicking-a-link-in-gmail-doesnt-trigger-my-jquery-event-what-can-i-do-to-fix-i)

[is JS supported by email clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)